# Sending email intent working on phone but not working on tablet in Android application

Tags: android, email, android-intent, tablet, mobile-phones

I'm trying to send email with an intent in my application. It works just fine on mobile phones, but it is not working on my tablet. Here is the mail intent code:

```
mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/html");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("email") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("email")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"asd@asd.com"});
                        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is my layout for phone:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bakanadanis_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bakana Ulaşın"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
```

And layout for 600dp tablet:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tab_merkezteskilatibg">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bakanadanis_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bakana Ulaşın"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Does anybody know what the issue might be? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting a crash or what's the symptom exactly? if you have any logs, paste it here.

Comment: i dont get any error message or something like that, just not work for tablet. I am capable of clicking button but not work for sending email action, i didnt find the problem in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your tablet has an email client application on it that passes all the conditions you are testing for in your various `if` conditions. Place debug logs at each stage and see how far you getting along in the process of trying to start your targeted app.

Comment: how can i check this situation and if it is not, how can i solve this problem. Because my app must work for tablet.

Comment: added more info to my answer. place debug logs. maybe you are too restrictive in if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("email") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("email")) { }. May need to relax. Also, easiest way to check is - are you able to open an email client outside the app i.e open a gmail app (or something similar) manually and send an email? if yes, then you should be able to launch that via your intent as well.

Comment: i solved problem with adding info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("Email") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("Email") into if statement. Thank you.